# How to manipulate the dictionary keys and values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary and I want to change the key of the dictionary into a unique value.

```
final_dict = {"name1":['raj','raj','raj'],"name2":['Rahul','Thor','max','Rahul'],"name3":['Jhon','Jhon'], "name4":['raj','raj'], "name5":['Rahul','Thor','max']}
```

First of all, I need unique values for each key like this

```
final_dict = {"name1":['raj'],"name2":['Thor','max','Rahul'],"name3":['Jhon'], "name4":['raj'], "name5":['Rahul','Thor','max']}
```

and then I need to convert the keys as values and vales as key
the final output I needed

```
output = {"raj":['name1','name4'], "('Thor','max','Rahul')":[name2,name5], "jhon":[name3]}
```

I tried this but I got only the unique values

```
mtype=[]
for key_name in final_dict:
    a = set(final[key_name])
    #print(tuple(a))
    mtype.append(tuple(a))
print(mtype)
u = set(mtype)
print(u)
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first shot at the problem. I'd carefully read through each line and make sure you understand what is going on. Feel free to ask follow ups in the comments!

```py
from collections import defaultdict

input = { ... }

output = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in input.items():
   unique_values = tuple(sorted(set(values)))
   output[unique_values].append(key)

output = dict(output)  # Transform defaultdict to a dict
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I need Rahul, Thor, max as one key

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. What about now (I updated my answer).

Comment: thanks @wKavey you are GOD for me and one more this I got the output like this {('raj',): ['name1', 'name4'], ('Rahul', 'Thor', 'max'): ['name2', 'name5'], ('Jhon',): ['name3']} in each of the key there is extra comma

Comment: so can we get the output as string insted of tuple

Comment: So currently the keys are of type `Tuple`. If you want them as strings, just cast the tuple to a string... `unique_values = str(tuple(sorted(.......`. Maybe even rename `unique_values` to `unique_key`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward way -

1. The `set()` takes care of the unique and the list comprehension below changes the dict items to item, key tuples.
2. `dict.setdefault()` allows appending each of the tuples into a blank list `[]` (key, value) pairs where the same key gets a list of values.

```
d = {}

l = [(i,k) for k,v in final_dict.items() for i in set(v)]

#print(l)
#[('raj', 'name1'), ('Thor', 'name2'), ('max', 'name2'), ('Rahul', 'name2'), 
#('Jhon', 'name3'), ('raj', 'name4'), ('Thor', 'name5'), ('max', 'name5'), 
#('Rahul', 'name5')]

for x, y in l:
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
    
print(d)
```

```
{'Jhon': ['name3'],
 'Rahul': ['name2', 'name5'],
 'Thor': ['name2', 'name5'],
 'max': ['name2', 'name5'],
 'raj': ['name1', 'name4']}
```